# Can you dial Twilio toll-free numbers from numbers outside of the USA?

Tags: twilio

I've called from countries (mainly in asia) to 1-800 and 1-888 numbers where the call doesn't get connected due to 'the number not existing'. Similarly, I've tried calling from the US to Canada to a toll free number and gotten the same result.

Does anyone know/confirm that if I were to purchase a toll free number from Twilio, it would be available for people to call from outside North America? If yes, would it still function as toll free? implying that the caller won't get charged for international calling?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried them. They don't. The number is invalid in other countries.